# First attempt at a strategy not generating orders in back testing

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am a very new Pine coder (though I have experience in c-like languages).

I have written my first strategy for back testing today, but no matter what I do, it isn't generating any orders in the testing range. There are no compile errors. Is there anyone out there who might be able to take a look at it?

I initially thought it might be a time range issue, but I seem to have that covered by using the timestamp(string) override, so I am a bit at a loss as to what may be the issue. The comments at the top explain what I am trying to do. Apologies in advance if it is something moronically simple. I am still in my first week of learning.

```
//@version=5
//This strategy has simple rules
//LONG when 
//1. the price closes below the EMA200
//2. the price closes above the Trend Trader Strategy by HPotter line (an alternative strategy is for the close price that crosses over the TTS line  in the previous bar - currently commnted out for testing)
//3. the STC Indicator by shayankm is green
//SHORT when
//1. the price closes above the EMA200
//2. the price closes below the Trend Trader Strategy by HPotter line (an alternative strategy is for the close price that crosses below the TTS line in the previous bar - currently commnted out for testing)
//3. the STC Indicator by shayankm is red
//CLOSE when
//the next bar closes (This strategy is intended to be tested for high frequency trading on 1-5 minute time frames or binary options)



strategy("Trend Trader Strategy with STC Indicator", overlay=true, initial_capital=1000, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.1, calc_on_every_tick=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=2, currency=currency.USD, pyramiding=0, backtest_fill_limits_assumption=0, slippage=0, process_orders_on_close=true, max_bars_back=100, linktoseries=false, shorttitle="")

// Backtesting Inputs
//startDate = input("0-01-01T00:00:00", "Start Date (YYYY-MM-DD)")
//endDate = input("2022-12-31T23:59:59", "End Date (YYYY-MM-DD)")

// Convert start and end dates to timestamps
startDateTimeStamp = timestamp("Jan 01 1900 00:00:00")
endDateTimeStamp = timestamp("Jan 01 2100 00:00:00")

// Calculate EMA 200
ema200 = ta.ema(close, 200)

// Trend Trader Strategy by HPotter
Length = input.int(21, minval=1)
Multiplier = input.float(3, minval=0.000001)
avgTR = ta.wma(ta.atr(1), Length)
highestC = ta.highest(Length)
lowestC = ta.lowest(Length)
hiLimit = highestC[1] - avgTR[1] * Multiplier
loLimit = lowestC[1] + avgTR[1] * Multiplier
trendLine = 0.0
pos = 0.0
trendLine := close > hiLimit and close > loLimit ? hiLimit :
             close < loLimit and close < hiLimit ? loLimit : nz(trendLine[1], close)
pos := close > trendLine[1] ? 1 : close < trendLine[1] ? -1 : nz(pos[1], 0)

// STC Indicator by shayankm
EEEEEE = input(12, 'Length')
BBBB = input(26, 'FastLength')
BBBBB = input(50, 'SlowLength')

AAAA(BBB, BBBB, BBBBB) =>
    fastMA = ta.ema(BBB, BBBB)
    slowMA = ta.ema(BBB, BBBBB)
    AAAA = fastMA - slowMA
    AAAA

AAAAA(EEEEEE, BBBB, BBBBB) =>
    AAA = input(0.5)
    var CCCCC = 0.0 //persistent variables
    var DDD = 0.0//persistent variables
    var DDDDDD = 0.0//persistent variables
    var EEEEE = 0.0//persistent variables
    BBBBBB = AAAA(close, BBBB, BBBBB)
    CCC = ta.lowest(BBBBBB, EEEEEE)
    CCCC = ta.highest(BBBBBB, EEEEEE) - CCC
    CCCCC := CCCC > 0 ? (BBBBBB - CCC) / CCCC * 100 : nz(CCCCC[1])
    DDD := na(DDD[1]) ? CCCCC : DDD[1] + AAA * (CCCCC - DDD[1])
    DDDD = ta.lowest(DDD, EEEEEE)
    DDDDD = ta.highest(DDD, EEEEEE) - DDDD
    DDDDDD := DDDDD > 0 ? (DDD - DDDD) / DDDDD * 100 : nz(DDDDDD[1])
    EEEEE := na(EEEEE[1]) ? DDDDDD : EEEEE[1] + AAA * (DDDDDD - EEEEE[1])
    EEEEE

mAAAAA = AAAAA(EEEEEE, BBBB, BBBBB)
mColor = mAAAAA > mAAAAA[1] ? color.new(color.green, 20) : color.new(color.red, 20)

// Entry conditions for short positions
enterShort = close < trendLine[1] and ema200 > close and mColor == color.red //the close for every position under the trend line
//enterShort = ta.crossunder(close, trendLine) and ema200 > close and mColor == color.red //the close from the crossunder of the trend line

// Entry conditions for long positions
enterLong = close > trendLine[1] and ema200 < close and mColor == color.green //the close for every position under the trend line
//enterLong = ta.crossover(close, trendLine) and ema200 < close and mColor == color.green //the close from the crossover the trend line

// Execute short trades
if time >= startDateTimeStamp and time < endDateTimeStamp and enterShort 
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    //alert("Sell Short", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

// Execute long trades
if time >= startDateTimeStamp and time < endDateTimeStamp and enterLong
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    //alert("Buy Long", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

// Close positions at the close of the next bar
if barstate.islast
    if strategy.position_size[0] < 0 and barstate.isconfirmed
        strategy.close("Short")

    if strategy.position_size[0] > 0 and barstate.isconfirmed
        strategy.close("Long")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code have two issues.

The first and main issue is that `color.new(color.green, 20)` and `color.green` are not the same. Therefore your entry conditions are never `true` because you have a condition like `mColor == color.green`.

What you should do is, you should create a new variable to see if STC is in an uptrend (green) and use that variable in your condition.

```
mColor = mAAAAA > mAAAAA[1] ? color.new(color.green, 20) : color.new(color.red, 20)
is_green = mAAAAA > mAAAAA[1]
is_red = not is_green

enterShort = close < trendLine[1] and ema200 > close and is_red //the close for every position under the trend line
enterLong = close > trendLine[1] and ema200 < close and is_green //the close for every position under the trend line
```

The next issue is, you don't want to use `barstate.islast` and `barstate.isconfirmed` in a backtest script. `barstate.islast` will never be `true` on the historical bars and `barstate.isconfirmed` will always be `true` on the historical bars.